# Access a Palo Alto VPN using Mint

Tags: vpn, linux, palo-alto

I'm Java developer and sometimes I need to test the development using the database of the client. So they give access using Windows and Mac by a program called `Palo Alto Global Protect` where I need to put my login, password and address of the gateway.

So I tried to configure the settings by myself but I couldn't connect. I asked the support team to configure it, they tried but it doesn't work.

I have one virtual machine using `Virtual Box` that I can install the program.

So there is one way to get the access to this `VPN` or configure it?

I'm using `Linux Mint`.

Comment: The support team didn't what? didn't reply? As for me the problem is not clear yet.

Comment: They tried to configure but not worked

Comment: would you please put some additional information regarding the error you are getting?

Comment: When I try to connect Linux get me a answer `The VPN connection failed` `The VPN connection failed to start becaus the VPN service failed to start`

Comment: Sorry for that, I didn't get the problem yet. But why don't you ask Google for this problem! Just search for: `The VPN connection failed The VPN connection failed to start because the VPN service failed to start`. Either ask Google or provide much more information such as what is your system, client's system ... I hope someone could help you if you provide sufficient information

Comment: I followed for some tutorials to access the VPN but didn't work. Thanks

Comment: *"So there is one way to get the access to this VPN or configure it?"* Yes....but I don't think that is really your question, rather it is probably more along the lines of "how can I get this working?" However, without knowing how the Palo Alto is configured and/or much more detail about hte problem, we can't provide a good answer. This is why end user questions are typically considered off topic here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing is that you are not using the official Global Protect client so you need and extra configuration step in the firewall. You need to define X-Auth support (on the firewall) and all related fields.

After that, you can use any SSL VPN Standard client. I confirm it works for me in Linux and IOS (the iphone thing, not the Cisco :P).

This link would be quite useful for you. http://blog.webernetz.net/2014/03/31/palo-alto-globalprotect-for-linux-with-vpnc/

Comment: I can't change configuration on the Firewall, but I will suggest to the support it.

Comment: Configuring X-Auth is your only chance of connecting because there are no Linux globalprotect client. If you need official explanation from Palo Alto, send this link to your support team https://live.paloaltonetworks.com/docs/DOC-5673

Comment: I passed to the support yours suggestion and he told me the X-Auth is configured

Comment: In this case, the remote job is done. Now, you have to configure your linux side. Check the tutorial pointed out in my answer

Comment: I've created my connection by GUI and it connect but when I try to ping one host, don't work. So I created one `conf` file to test and it worked but the internet connection stopped.

Comment: Just a clarification note for this question. Palo alto offers two types of VPN IPSEC and SSL. There is a licensing fee for IPSEC, so some sites will only offer the SSL version. The above answer relates to the ipsec VPN and I don't think has any relevance for SSL vpn.

Comment: @KorXo, I have recently extended the awesome FLOSS VPN client [openconnect](https://www.infradead.org/openconnect) to support PAN GlobalProtect, without any additional IT configuration. You can read more about it on [my answer here](http://askubuntu.com/a/838882/139469) or [go download the source from Github](https://github.com/dlenski/openconnect/commits/globalprotect).